# Moving a object based on its rotation in three.js

Tags: math, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to move a cube in three.js based on its rotation but not sure on how to go about it.

As of now I can rotate the cube's z-rotation with the A & D keys.  And with the W key I would like it to move forward relative to its rotation.

From 2D I would so something along the lines of:

```
float angle = GradToRad(obj.rotation);
obj.x = obj.x + cos(angle) * velocity;
obj.y = obj.y + sin(angle) * velocity;
```

Here's an image of the current implementation.
[image: 3D Cube three.js]

How can I apply something similar in three.js?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Objects can be considered to be facing their positive-Z axis. So to move an object forward, relative to it's own coordinate system, you can use

```
Object3D.translateZ( distance );
```

three.js r.57

Comment: Yes but just translating along the Z axis will not allow my object to move relative to its rotation.  Meaning as I turn around the object I wish for it to move along its "facing".

Comment: In which direction does your object "face" when it's rotataion vector is ( 0, 0, 0 )? That is the local direction you want to move in after rotation is applied.

Comment: I roatate around the Z-axis.

Comment: In which direction does your object "face" when it's rotataion vector is ( 0, 0, 0 )?

Comment: With no rotation the cube faces (0, 1, 0)

Comment: Well, then, did you try Object3D.translateY( distance )?

Comment: Oh boy do I feel silly now!  TRANSLATE!  Is not the same as setting a position...  I figured there was some more advanced math behind this but yeah okay. And yeah it works :) Thanks a bunch mate!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to express both rotation and translation in a single (homogenous projective) [4×4 matrix](http://threejs.org/docs/57/#Reference/Math/Matrix4). The [`Object3D.matrix`](http://threejs.org/docs/57/#Reference/Core/Object3D) member in three.js already does that, although you might have to set `matrixAutoUpdate` to `false` to use that directly. Then you can move use the `translate` method to move the object in its own reference frame.

Comment: It is highly unadvisable for users to mess with the object matrix directly in three.js. Only do so if you really know what you are doing and are familiar with the internal workings of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2D method is exactly how I did it in three.js. For the Y position I'm using a terrain collision technique (which still needs work);