# Send object backwards down its -z axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I was wondering how would i go about getting an objects rotation (which changes alot of the time) and lets say something simple like on click send the object down its relative/local -z axis...

so basically send the character backwards no matter what or where its rotation is?

I managed to have a go and got it to work but only when facing z or -z the x axis is completely screwed tho any ideas or easier way?

```
const object = sceneExport.getObjectByName( "player" );
  const dirToPlayer = this._FindPlayer();

    
      const controlObject = object;
      const _Q = new THREE.Quaternion();
      const _A = new THREE.Vector3();
      const _R = controlObject.quaternion.clone();
    

     
      const m = new THREE.Matrix4();
      m.lookAt(
          new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
          dirToPlayer,
          new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
      _R.setFromRotationMatrix(m);
  
      controlObject.quaternion.copy(_R);
   
    
   this._parent.SetQuaternion(this._target.quaternion);
```

thanks guys

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927708/moving-a-object-based-on-its-rotation-in-three-js

Comment: @WestLangley you are right nothing to do with this questions but you by any chance know how to invert the above code do you i tried controlObject.quaternion.invert() didn't have the desired affect.... im basically trying to iget the opposite of dirToPlayer

Comment: I assume you are inquiring about  `Vector3.negate()`.